# Borrowing errors whilst mutating in for loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am having issues with the borrow checker and temporary values in rust.

I'm hoping to find a solution to this specific problem as well as better learn how to handle this kind of situation in the future. I originally started off with a `for_each` but ran into issues terminating early.

I considered moving the logic of `check_foo` into `update_foo`, however this wouldn't work well for my real world solution; the MRE focuses on the compilation issues vs what I'm trying to achieve in the whole program.

---

**Edit:** Is there a way for me to achieve this in a purely functional approach?

---

I want to iterate over a range of numbers, updating a `Vec<Foo>` and potentially returning early with a value. Below is a minimal reproducible example of my code with the same errors:

I tried tried implementing as:

```rust
fn run<'a>(mut foos: Vec<Foo>) -> Vec<&'a u32> {
    let mut bar: Vec<&u32> = vec![];

    for num in 0..10 {
        for foo in &mut foos {
            update_foo(foo);

            let checked_foo = check_foo(&foo);
            if checked_foo.is_empty() {
                bar = checked_foo;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    bar
}

/* `fn update_foo` and `fn check_foo` definitions same as below */
```

but this resulted in:

```rust
21 | for foo in &mut foos {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^ `foos` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

To overcome this I added the use of `Rc` and `RefCell` to allow me to iterate over a reference whilst still being able to mutate:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Foo {
    updated: bool,
}

fn run<'a>(foos: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Foo>>>) -> Vec<&'a u32> {
    let mut bar: Vec<&u32> = vec![];

    for num in 0..10 {
        for foo in &foos {
            update_foo(&mut foo.borrow_mut());

            let checked_foo = check_foo(&foo.borrow());
            if checked_foo.is_empty() {
                bar = checked_foo;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    bar
}

fn update_foo(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.updated = true
}

fn check_foo(foo: &Foo) -> Vec<&u32> {
    if foo.updated {
        vec![&0, &1, &2]
    } else {
        vec![]
    }
}
```

which results in:

```rust
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
26 |             let checked_foo = check_foo(&foo.borrow());
   |                                          ------------ temporary value created here
...
33 |     bar
   |     ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `foos`
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
23 |         for foo in &foos {
   |                    ----- `foos` is borrowed here
...
33 |     bar
   |     ^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

Comment: Can you post the original, simple code you had, before you went down into the weeds trying to work around the errors?

Comment: Hi Sebastian. What I've posted is an MRE of my code. The equivalnent of `check_foo` has more logic going on inside but otherwise it's not very different. `for foo in &mut foos` was my first error in this fn which I focused on solving before moving on.

Comment: Okay, there are a few things going wrong here. References should only be returned when you have some struct that can own the data and lives longer than the reference to it. Otherwise, you need to make sure the data you're passing around is owned. I assume you don't want to transfer the ownership of `foos` to the `run` function, since then you can't ever reuse it. This should therefore be a reference.

Comment: Any time you return some new data that isn't pointing to data from an incoming reference, you should have this be owned, so that it can continue living after the function returns. It should be noted that the signature of `check_foo` is expanded to `fn check_foo(foo: &'a Foo) -> Vec<&'a u32>` which is not what you want. This signature means that you're restricting `foo` to live longer than the elements of the vector you're returning.

Comment: `bar` will be "referencing data owned by the current function" because the borrow checker understands `check_foo` to return references to the `foo` that are passed in. Since the `Vec` `foos` is owned by the function, it will be dropped before returning, and Rust thinks you are returning references to a struct that has been dropped.

Comment: I see! Thank you for taking the time to go through this Marcel, much appreciated. WIll bear this in mind in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you plan to do with this, but it seems to me like a few of the references you're using should be owned. Here's what I came up with.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Foo {
    updated: bool,
}

fn run(foos: &mut Vec<Foo>) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut bar: Vec<u32> = vec![];

    for num in 0..10 {
        for foo in foos.iter_mut() { 
            update_foo(foo);

            let checked_foo = check_foo(&foo);
            if checked_foo.is_empty() {
                bar = checked_foo;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    bar
}

fn update_foo(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.updated = true
}

fn check_foo(foo: &Foo) -> Vec<u32> {
    if foo.updated {
        vec![0, 1, 2]
    } else {
        vec![]
    }
}
```

References should be used when you expect some other struct to own the objects you are referring to, but here you're constructing new vectors with new data, so you should keep the elements owned.

Comment: Hi Marcel. Thanks for the response. I just updated my post with a missing `break;` after `bar = checked_foo;` which hopefully sheds light on what I'm trying to achieve. Essentially I want to search through the `foo`'s, updating them and eventually returning early. In my MRE this might not be clear.

Comment: And why do you do this 10 times? Did you mean to break the outer loop?

Comment: In my real code i'm iterating over a `u32`, i just put `10` for the example. The logic itself isn't all implemented here  asmy focus for the question is just on the compilation errors.

Comment: your solution looks good. Could you elobrate on what I was doing wrong and how your solution solves it? I'm still unsure as to how your solution is able to iterate over `foos`.

Comment: If you could post the original code before you added `Rc` and `RefCell` I can explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Ah ok. Gotchya. Will update my question, showing the full, original attempt.